# Master-Details-Page (SplitView) for iOS-App with Xamarin and MVVMCross 6

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, master-detail, splitview

I am currently developing an **iOS-App** with Xamarin and **MVVMCross 6** and I would like to create a "SplitView".

[Skatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ3dy.png)

The SplitView should consist of a Master and a Details page.
In portrait mode only the Master page OR the Details page should be shown.

If the screen of the device is large enough, both pages should be displayed. The Details page should change when an action is performed on the Master page.

**It would be nice if someone could briefly explain which storyboard elements, views, ViewModels and navigation elements are needed to realize such a SplitView.**

Please do not simply link to the page: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/ios-sidebar?scroll=1300

Thank you and best regards

**Addition: What have I done so far.**
I have often implemented a "normal" navigation from one page to another without problems. 
I used the Designer to place a SplitViewController on the StoryBoard. Then I created a .cs file for each controller (e.g. RootViewController.cs).

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChcI5.png)

The views look like this:

```
[MvxFromStoryboard("LaunchScreen")]
public partial class MasterViewController : MvxViewController<MasterViewModel>
```

Then I created a Root, Master and Detail ViewModel.
When navigating to the RootViewModel

```
await _navigationService.Navigate<RootViewModel>();
```

But then I get the following error:

> $exception    {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object   at
>   MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel
>   (MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request,
>   MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState,
>   MvvmCross.Navigation.EventArguments.IMvxNavigateEventArgs
>   navigationArgs) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\ViewModels\MvxViewModelLoader.cs:62    at
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensions.LoadViewModel
>   (MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.IMvxIosView iosView) [0x0004d] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Ios\Views\MvxViewControllerExtensions.cs:36
>   at MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewExtensions.OnViewCreate
>   (MvvmCross.Views.IMvxView view, System.Func`1[TResult]
>   viewModelLoader) [0x00012] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Views\MvxViewExtensions.cs:24    at
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensions.OnViewCreate
>   (MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.IMvxIosView iosView) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Ios\Views\MvxViewControllerExtensions.cs:17
>   at
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxViewControllerAdapter.HandleViewDidLoadCalled
>   (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Ios\Views\MvxViewControllerAdapter.cs:24 
>   at (wrapper delegate-invoke)
>   .invoke_void_object_EventArgs(object,System.EventArgs)   at
>   MvvmCross.Base.MvxDelegateExtensions.Raise (System.EventHandler
>   eventHandler, System.Object sender) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Base\MvxDelegateExtensions.cs:13    at
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.Base.MvxEventSourceViewController.ViewDidLoad
>   () [0x00006] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Ios\Views\Base\MvxEventSourceViewController.cs:62
>   at MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxViewController.ViewDidLoad ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Ios\Views\MvxViewController.cs:60    at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(intptr,intptr,intptr)
>   at UIKit.UIWindow.set_RootViewController (UIKit.UIViewController
>   value) [0x0000d] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.10.0.17/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIWindow.g.cs:394
>   at
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Presenters.MvxIosViewPresenter.SetWindowRootViewController
>   (UIKit.UIViewController controller,
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Presenters.Attributes.MvxRootPresentationAttribute
>   attribute) [0x00025] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Ios\Presenters\MvxIosViewPresenter.cs:624
>   at
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Presenters.MvxIosViewPresenter.SetupWindowRootNavigation
>   (UIKit.UIViewController viewController,
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Presenters.Attributes.MvxRootPresentationAttribute
>   attribute) [0x00023] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Ios\Presenters\MvxIosViewPresenter.cs:260
>   at
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Presenters.MvxIosViewPresenter.ShowRootViewController
>   (UIKit.UIViewController viewController,
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Presenters.Attributes.MvxRootPresentationAttribute
>   attribute, MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00267]
>   in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Ios\Presenters\MvxIosViewPresenter.cs:198
>   } System.NullReferenceException

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Okay, good point. I'm going to complete my steps.

Comment: Great, I've voted for reopening now, but you'll need more votes...